# Advice to become talented in mathematics.

Tags: soft-question, proof-writing

Is Talented in Mathematics means your ability to memorize a lot of tricks and recalling them at the suitable time?

I want to be Talented and Gifted in Mathematics, Could you give me your advice?

Comment: I do not know why people vote down my question ...... if me question break any rule in this site ..... please tell me.....thanks.

Comment: It's not that your question is 'bad' Marwa, it is just not a good fit for the Q&A style of this site. Hopefully someone will be able to point you to somewhere that you can get information about this though!

Comment: For one thing, your tags on the question are ludicrous.  This should be tagged "soft-question" and that is all.  The other point is that the question itself can't be answered with an answer you might accept. For example, if I asked a top footballer "I want to be a world-class striker, what should I do" the answer of "be born with immense physical ability and then play soccer among top flight competition many hours a day from childhood on" would be accurate, but not what you wanted to hear!

Comment: I will correct it ... sorry I am new and do not know this name of tags..... I apologize another time.

Comment: @ThomasRussell ..... thank u for your advice.

Comment: I don't provide you and advice because I am an amateur mathematician but Sir Ken Robinson has a theory about the creativity, and he is author of books. From my viewpoint it is very difficult to be a top mathematician, but I believe that it is possible do a humble contribution in this field if one study a lot.The more important is if you has an advisor or some professor that can help you in your university. With respect @MarkFischler comment I am not agree 100% with it, note for example that footballers, and is my opinion aren't all athletes, but seem nice because soccer is a comercial product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Hey I am a kid can you make me understand Fermat's last theorem then I will think you have reached that position,being gifted doesn't mean that you get yourself to be a crammer.You need to be a person who understands the art of mathematics.Then only I think you will achieve that.